# Should different servers translate unix timestamps as different dates?

Tags: php, unix, date, timestamp

Whilst working on a UI update for a client, I noticed the dates associated with all the articles were out by a day. I figured I'd screwed something up during my changes, but to be sure, threw together a little php test file that gave me some odd results. The test file is just;

```
<?php
$date = 1246053600;
echo 'unix: ',$date,', converted: ',date('d/m/Y', $date);
?>
```

If I run the above code on my localhost I get:

> unix: 1246053600, converted:
>   26/06/2009

But if I run it on the production server I get:

> unix: 1246053600, converted:
>   27/06/2009

Notice the day difference between the two? What's happening here?! Surely converting a unix timestamp to a date doesn't have any server specific dependancies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your servers might be set to two different time zones, and they're interpreting the timestamp as the number of seconds since midnight january 1st 1970 *GMT*. The dates may not be off by a whole day, but just part of a day, enough to make it cross over the midnight boundary.

Comment: It turned out to be exactly this; the timezone settings on the production server *just* bumped the date into the next day.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the $date value you are providing is presumed to be in UTC.  If you [use gmdate, you will get the same result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) on both servers.  Otherwise, the date and time displayed will be adjusted according to the servers' timezone.  You can use the O (capital oh) code to print out the timezone to make the current setting on each server clear:

`echo 'unix: ',$date,', converted: ',date('d/m/Y O', $date);`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before. I found that the time zone in the php.ini from my development machine was different from the production server.

I'd say it is worth checking that out.